# CUDA filter integers in parallel

Tags: concurrency, cuda

What is the canonical (or in fact, any working) way to achieve the following result:

Given all values of `uint32_t`, I would like to apply a filter function (predicate?) (`uint32_t` -> `bool`) so that only certain integers remain, and save those into an array. The array itself is in the `__constant__` memory, but I guess it could be moved to generic `__device__` memory instead. There is a practical upper limit on the number of accepted `uint32_t`s, e.g. 15000.

My current solution is to perform this in a `__host__` code, with the obvious `for` loop involved, but the solution is impractically slow. Instead, I would like to implement this filtering as a `__global__` kernel.

The solution I have in mind would be a kernel that calls the filtering function, and stores the positive result into an array. The index at which it writes would need to be somehow atomically incremented. This is where the crux of the task lies - how would I go about ensuring the concurrent correctness whilst maintaining performance?

My code is targeting the Jetson TX1, therefore the Compute Capability is `5.3`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use the fast **CUB device primitives**. More specifically the one of [`cub::DeviceSelect`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_select.html). This one *preserve the order*.

Alternatively, you can use the **atomic-based** solution you talk about, but be aware that the order will *not be preserved*. This solution is simple and relatively fast on modern GPUs with few SM but probably do not scale very well on high-end GPUs (because of the possible contention on the atomics between SMs).

Another alternative is to use a **parallel-scan**. This solution is quite complex to implement (and thus more bug prone), but *preserve the order*. It can be faster than the atomic solution and should scale better (if the implementation is cleverly written).

Finally, you can make use of **blocking** and **shared memory** to improve your implementation (especially the parallel-scan). Blocking can reduce contention and unnecessary communications between CUDA cores. You can reuse the [block-wide primitives](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/group___block_module.html) of CUB if you are not an experienced CUDA developer.